Sequelize-cli migrations
Ao rodar o comando para executar as migrqtions é devolvido no console o seguinte erro:
Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.22.9, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.7]
Loaded configuration file "api/config/config.json". Using environment "development".
ERROR: Unexpected token '('
Mesmo depois de fazer todas as configurações de path no .sequelizerc.
Como resolver esse erro ?

Não duplique perguntas, siga as orientações fornecidas na pergunta original: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/596219/3635. Se precisar comentar faça na pergunta original.
